# Make meld display user friendly title when used as git difftool

Tags: git, meld, difftool

I use meld as my git difftool.  Often when comparing my current state against a particular branch (for example) like this:

```
git difftool -d branchname
```

Unless it's obvious from the code state, I have a hard time figuring out which is my current state, and which is the branch I'm comparing against, as they are both labeled with tmp directories.  Is there a way to instruct git to instruct meld to add a more user-friendly title to the left and right panels?  (e.g. "branchname" and "HEAD")?  I'm up for a little hacking if necessary.

Comment: A branch name instead the left/right would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The directories are created by git. Meld just compare the directory given to it. You can create a PR to change this.

[Source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d807c4a01db2b06db047fc6d5d18ac25c8f05bd7/builtin/difftool.c#L362-L363):

```
strbuf_addf(&ldir, "%s/left/", tmpdir);
strbuf_addf(&rdir, "%s/right/", tmpdir);
```